# Spring batch: element unreachable in partition

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I try to partition the step, but I get "Configuration problem: The element [step1] is unreachable".

```
<step id="partitionement" next="otherStep">
    <partition step="step1" partitioner="bean1">
        <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="threadPoolTaskExecutor" />
    </partition>
</step>

<batch:step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
         ...
        </tasklet>
</batch:step>

<step="otherStep">
    ...
</step>

<bean id="bean1" class="OneClass"/>
```

I try to put next parameter in step 1 but I got also the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. The part
      
         
           ...
          
       
have to be outside the